# URL issue in MVC4 Mobile website (Razor View Engine) with AJAX

Tags: ajax, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a mobile website in MVC4 (using Razor view Engine).
The issue I am facing is that When I navigate to different View using RedirectToAction() method, the new view is served but the URL remains the same in the browser.

I searched about it and found that If I disable the AJAX on my page (by setting attribute [data-ajax=false]) then It start working fine(i.e. correct URL is displayed). But Ajax stops working.

But my problem is that I can not disable AJAX for mobile website & I need to display correct URL for each page.

EDIT:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string btnSelection)
{
  //Some code here... 
  //Then redirect to another View using following command:
  return RedirectToAction("SelectTask", "Task");
}
```

But to achieve proper URL display in MVC4 mobile, I have to set following attribute in View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Task", FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = false }))
```

But this stops the AJAX. Any ideas how to fix this using AJAX?

Please help if you can asap.

Thanks.

Comment: You should redirect to an action not to a view ... Am I missing something ??? Show your Code !

Comment: @Arno : I have added the code in Edit. Plz check.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is not for navigating.  You must submit form if you have data to save or use a link (e.g. `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")`) to redirect to the other view.

Comment: Hmm, but I need to fill session before I navigate to another view. Is it possible to submit form when I navigate to another View.

Comment: @AshishDiwakar you have two choices, with ajax if you submit then you will not be redirected on the server but you could redirect on the client after success using javascript.  The more usual approach in this case would not be to use ajax but submit the form normally and you would get redirected fine.